# DENSE_RANK() or ROW_NUMBER() - to create groupings

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to use the DENSE_RANK() OVER PARTITION to create a set of rankings for some data. The data is sorted by date, date time and then Status. Its the date time and status that I need to rank it by , below is the desired rank output.

[image]

I've used various DENSE_RANK and ROW_NUMBER combinations but haven't been able to get the right grouping.
Is it possible to get the ranking how I need them?

Comment: you can use https://senseful.github.io/text-table/ to create text tables instead of using screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Using [**`lag()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) and a `case` expression to compare `ctstatus` with previous `ctstatus`, and when different return `1`. This is assuming you want to reset the rank per person and day, if not move them from the `partition by` to the beginning of the `order by` of the `over()` clauses. Then using `sum() over()` for a running total as `rnk`.

```
;with cte as (
  select t.*
    /* compare ctstatus with previous ctstatus, when different return by 1 */
    , inc = case when ctstatus = lag(ctstatus) over (
      partition by 
          description -- for each person
        , atdate --for each day ? 
      order by atdatetime 
      ) then 0 else 1 end
  from t
)
select 
    atdatetime
  , atdate
  , atext
  , description
  , ctstatus
  , rnk = sum(inc) over (partition by description, atdate order by atdatetime)
from cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description and sample data it's impossible to know what to group or partition by so I'm ignoring that aspect of this for now. That said, here's how your could do this using a the `SUM() OVER` window aggregate.

**Sample data**

```
if object_id('tempdb..#x') is not null drop table #x;

create table #x
(
  ATDATETIME datetime, 
  ATDATE date, 
  ATEXT varchar(10),
  CTSTATUS varchar(30)
);
create clustered index cl_x on #x(ATDATETIME); -- for a sort-free execution plan

insert #x values
(getdate()-1.90, cast(getdate()-1.90 as date), 1397, 'BK tomorrow...'),
(getdate()-1.85, cast(getdate()-1.85 as date), 1397, 'AVAILABLE'),
(getdate()-1.83, cast(getdate()-1.83 as date), 1397, 'AVAILABLE'),
(getdate()-1.81, cast(getdate()-1.81 as date), 1397, 'AVAILABLE'),
(getdate()-1.75, cast(getdate()-1.75 as date), 1397, 'AVAILABLE'),
(getdate()-1.71, cast(getdate()-1.71 as date), 1397, 'Went away'),
(getdate()-1.67, cast(getdate()-1.67 as date), 1397, 'AVAILABLE'),
(getdate()-1.63, cast(getdate()-1.63 as date), 1397, 'AVAILABLE'),
(getdate()-1.60, cast(getdate()-1.60 as date), 1397, 'AVAILABLE'),
(getdate()-1.56, cast(getdate()-1.56 as date), 1397, 'AVAILABLE'),
(getdate()-1.55, cast(getdate()-1.55 as date), 1397, 'Snuck out for beer'),
(getdate()-1.50, cast(getdate()-1.50 as date), 1397, 'AVAILABLE'),
(getdate()-1.46, cast(getdate()-1.46 as date), 1397, 'AVAILABLE');
```

**Solution**

```
select ATDATETIME, ATDATE, ATEXT, CTSTATUS, RNK =
  SUM(IIF(CTSTATUS = 'AVAILABLE' AND CTSTATUS_LAG1 = 'AVAILABLE',0,1))
    OVER (ORDER BY ATDATETIME)
from
(
  select *, CTSTATUS_LAG1 = LAG(CTSTATUS, 1) OVER (ORDER BY ATDATETIME)
  from #x
) tlag;
```

**Results**

```
ATDATETIME              ATDATE     ATEXT      CTSTATUS                       RNK
----------------------- ---------- ---------- ------------------------------ -----------
2017-10-30 14:00:11.990 2017-10-30 1397       BK tomorrow...                 1
2017-10-30 15:12:11.990 2017-10-30 1397       AVAILABLE                      2
2017-10-30 15:40:59.990 2017-10-30 1397       AVAILABLE                      2
2017-10-30 16:09:47.990 2017-10-30 1397       AVAILABLE                      2
2017-10-30 17:36:11.990 2017-10-30 1397       AVAILABLE                      2
2017-10-30 18:33:47.990 2017-10-30 1397       Went away                      3
2017-10-30 19:31:23.990 2017-10-30 1397       AVAILABLE                      4
2017-10-30 20:28:59.990 2017-10-30 1397       AVAILABLE                      4
2017-10-30 21:12:11.990 2017-10-30 1397       AVAILABLE                      4
2017-10-30 22:09:47.990 2017-10-30 1397       AVAILABLE                      4
2017-10-30 22:24:11.990 2017-10-30 1397       Snuck out for beer             5
2017-10-30 23:36:11.990 2017-10-30 1397       AVAILABLE                      6
2017-10-31 00:33:47.990 2017-10-31 1397       AVAILABLE                      6
```